# How do I fake a method on $scope of an angular function using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've inherited some broken tests that I'm trying to get working. We are using Angular 1.5 with Jasmine. In a 'real' controller we have the following:

```
function myfunction() {
  $scope.stop = function() {
     $interval.cancel(promise);
     $timeout.cancel(timeout);
  };
  .........
```

This function get called at the top of the controller.

in my test file I set up interval and timeout using:

```
 'use strict';

var $scope;
var $timeout;


describe('Pas', function(){
describe('PasController', function() {
    var $this;
    var $rootscope;
    var PasService;
    var $interval = jasmine.createSpy('$interval', $interval).and.callThrough();
    var $timeout = jasmine.createSpy('$timeout', $timeout).and.callThrough();

    beforeEach(module('CL.Pas'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _PasService_, _$interval_, _$timeout_) {
        $rootscope = _$rootScope_;
        PasService = _PasService_;
        $interval  = _$interval_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;

        var data = {
            "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "SectionSlug": "string",
            "SectionName": "PAS",
            "Sections": [
                {
                    id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                    Mandatory: true,
                    description: "test 1",
                    name: "Section 1",
                    status: "Not Started"
                },
                {
                    id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003",
                    Mandatory: false,
                    description: "test 3",
                    name: "Section 3",
                    status: "Started"
                },
                {
                    id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                    Mandatory: true,
                    description: "test 2",
                    name: "Section 2",
                    status: "Not Started"
                }
            ],
            Forms: []
        };

        spyOn(PasService, 'canSubmitMandatorySections').and.callFake(getFakePromise({Result: false}));
        spyOn(PasService, 'canSubmitOptionalSections').and.callFake(getFakePromise({Result: false}));
        spyOn($interval, 'cancel');
        spyOn($timeout, 'cancel');


        $this = _$controller_('PasController', {sections: data, PasService: PasService, canSubmitIndividual: true, $scope: $scope,  $timeout : $timeout, $interval: $interval});
    }));

    it('should split available sections', function () {
        $rootscope.$apply();

        expect($this.sections.mandatory.length).toEqual(2);
        expect($this.sections.optional.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
});
```

At the point my tests run I receive a **TypeError:Cannot set property 'Stop' of undefined.** How do I fake this in my test?

It errors in the setup when trying to set $this from *$controller*

Comment: Can you post the entire test please? Or provide a link to jsbin etc? That 'Stop' doesn't appear to be referring to what you've written ($scope.stop).

Comment: @rrd I've changed the question to show the whole test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to instanciate scope `$scope = $rootscope.$new();`